# How to get posts by category at /%category%/ url?

Tags: categories, archive-template

I want to display titles of all posts of the "News" category at `http://example.com/news`. I have setup permalinks as `http://example.com/%category%/%postname%/`. I use `archive.php` template which, according to WordPress Theme Handbook, is *" used when visitors request posts by category"*.

This is what I have in **archive.php**

```php
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php the_archive_title(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

It returns not what I want:

> Category: News

What is the correct way to return the list of posts belonging to the "News" category in this example? Is the `archive.php` correct template for that?

P.S. I know similar questions have been asked, but answers I've found contain a numerous different ways that seem to be a bit hacky. I'm looking to a correct native way to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the archive.php correct template for that?

`archive.php` is the most common file to load any kind of archive posts. But anytime the user loads a category archive page, WordPress template system looks for files in this order:

category-slug.php → category-id.php → category.php → archive.php → index.php

If you want to create a specific template for news category, you should use one of the following:

`category-news.php`: will work only for the news category

`category.php`: will work for all categories

To get the list of posts under News category, you should use the following code:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>

    <h1 class="archive-title">Category: <?php single_cat_title( '', false ); ?></h1>

<?php while(the_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <h2 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2><br />
    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

For detailed information about category templates, I recommend you to read [this article](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-category-templates-in-wordpress/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer on template, but my main question is how do I get the list of posts belonging to the "News" category when I visit `http://example.com/news` url?

Comment: @qwaz sorry, I totally misunderstood your question. I've updated my answer. ;)